# How to set direction for both of persian and english text in <p> tag using css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How to set css for persian and english text in one `<p></p>`? All my text are in `p` tag. Direction for persian must be `rtl` and english must be `ltr`.

**html**:

```
<p>
 این یک تست است.

Test{
required int a = 1;
}
</p>
```

**css**:

```
p :not([dir=ltr]){ 
   direction: rtl;
   text-align: justify;
 }
```

What is should I do? I just can change css and html files read from `Wordpress`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need different text directions in the `p` you can add `span`s to the `p`. Each `span` can have it's own text direction. The [`lang`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) attribute can be used on the `span`s to inform browser and search engines about the languages. I recommend to use UTF-8 as [charset](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) to support the letters. Example:

HTML:

```
<p>
  <span lang="fa">این یک تست است.</span>
  <span lang="en">Test</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
span[lang="fa"] { direction: rtl; text-align: justify; }
span[lang="en"] { direction: ltr; text-align: justify; }
```

Update: use of `lang` in CSS selectors as recommended in comments

Comment: +1 , but you could use only the attribute `[lang="fa"] {direction:rtl;}` where the rest of the page will be by defaut english. (make it simple :) )

Comment: Right. But we don't know the main language of the page. So, I added the first part of your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Persian text in paragraph, add the `rtl` class to your `<p>` as in: `<p class="rtl">Persian text here</p>`.

Then, define the `rtl` class as follow:

```
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

For your regular text, there's no need for any extra class (`<p>Regular text here (non-Persian)</p>`).

Remember to have your regular justified `p` style as

```
p {
   text-align: justify;
}
```

or better still as a class (`justify`) to use as is `<p class="justify">Justified regular text here</p>` with the style defined as below (for a regular non-Persian text justified text):

```
.justify {
   text-align: justify;
}
```

So: for a justified Persian text, `<p class="rtl justify">Justified Persian text here</p>`.

To implement this in your WordPress theme, first, login and go to your *Dashboard*.

Once there, hover on the **Appearance** menu at your left-hand-side and click on the **Edit** sub-menu; that will take you to the *Edit Themes* page (or do add `theme-editor.php` to the URL of your right after `.../wp-admin/` as in: `.../wp-admin/theme-editor.php`, where `...` is the regular path to your WordPress installation).

***Please note: it's always advisable to back up your file(s) before any performing any modification.***

Then, scroll to the last portion of your `style.css` which will be the default editable one on the theme editor page and add your custom snippet there *(refer to the snippet below)*.

```
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
.justify {
   text-align: justify;
}
```

*Remember to click on the **Update File** button so as to effect your modifications!*

After this stage, you can readily use your custom styles with ease.

Go to your **Posts** or **Pages** and select a content you want to edit.

On the resulting *Edit Post* or *Edit Page*, look close to the *Publication widget* at your right-hand-side and click on the **Text** option (next to the **Visual** option of the text editor) in order to switch to the *Text mode*.

You can then apply your custom style (`.rtl` and `.justify`) to the content you want affected without distorting all existing ones (refer to the summary snippet below).

```
<p>Regular text here</p>
<p class="rtl">Persian text here</p>
<p class="justify">Justified Regular text here</p>
<p class="rtl justify">Justified Persian text here</p>
```

Do save and or publish your *post* or *page* and open it in a browser to see your changes in action.

Comment: I just can change css file and html file read from wordpress. So I can not use from `<p class="rtl">Persian text here</p>`

Comment: You can do that, by using the **Text** mode when creating or editing the content of your page. To set the styles, go to the **Edit** section of your theme, under **Appearance**, add it below the content of your `style.css`. Remember to save; that's all you need to do. ;-) Will update my response to capture that soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
P
{
    direction:rtl;
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}
```

You can use this code in a CSS file or `style` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use`:lang(fa)`

```css
:lang(fa)   {
    font-family: "Iran Yekan";
    font-size: 100px;
    ...
}
```